# Working with file that has had several commits

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a file which I've been working on for quite some time. My boss had me working on a branch that other people have been working on. There have been several commits to a file which I've been working on. `How do I merge my changes into the file since it's had several commits now?` I have not pulled the recent commits yet.,

Comment: Are you asking for the command (`git merge`) or a strategy to deal with conflicts?

Comment: The answer is in your comment, `git merge` is your friend here. You can check the [community guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide/816636#816636) for more questions that you may have:

Comment: @dubes Im merging same files on same branch thouhg..

Comment: `git pull --rebase`? This would put your changes on top of everything else. You will probably still need to resolve conflicts.

Comment: You could test using git fetch and git merge --no-ff --no-commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already.. I'd make sure to branch off of this shared branch (let's call it `develop`) your coworkers are working on.

Re-apply your changes on top of the latest commits from the shared `develop` branch

```
git pull --rebase origin develop
```

Check for any conflicts your change may have made, resolve them.

```
git status
```

If there are conflicts you will need to add them back to staging, and continue the rebase.  Depending on the conflicts and how far you are behind, you may need to do this step several times.

```
git add <files_with_conflicts>
git rebase --continue
```

At this point, you are good to merge, and share your changes.

```
git checkout develop
git merge <your_local_branch>
git push origin develop
```